# Android Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an Action Bar in my app for Android 4.0.3. Every tab has some buttons (a sort of continue) that would change the fragment but not the tab. I followed the official developer guide on http://developer.android.com but it doesn't work.

This is what I want :

[image]

Is it possible this type of interaction with Action Bar Sherlock?

Comment: If I understand well you want to do a navigation in the current tab ? Since ViewPager are using Adapter, I don't think about a simple way to achieve that :s ActionBarSherlock is the same as the official ActionBar, it's just compatible with previous version of Android. Can't you just open a new Activity on click with a previous button ?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I need! I would use Activity too but unfortunately I can't, I'm obliged to keep the bar.

Comment: Can you post your code ? ViewPager and the ViewPager adapter ? The solution is here :)

Comment: This is my code :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843944/actionbar-and-fragments-on-ics-4-0-3

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can specify tabs behaviour you need by properly overriding tabs callback class method onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft).
It shold be look like

```
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            //Here we look if current fragment aren't default fragment for this tab
            //Remember that detached fragments are still managed by system, so manage it the way u need
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            // ft.attach(mFragment);
            if (mFragment.getTag().equals("defaultFragment"))
                ft.show(mFragment);
            else {
                ft.detach(mFragment);

                mFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("defaultFragment");
                if (mFragment == null)
                    mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, mFragment, "defaultFragment");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't understand if your mFragment is the navigation fragment or the tab one? This is my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843944/actionbar-and-fragments-on-ics-4-0-3